# Security to run stored procedure with CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure `MyStoredProcedure` which uses a CTE and returns it.

```
create procedure MyStoredProcedure
as
    WITH mytemptable(foo) AS 
    (
        SELECT bar 
        FROM mytable
    )
    SELECT foo 
    FROM mytemptable
```

I have a fairly fixed requirement for security. There is a fixed user `MyUser` that I can give a role `MyRole`, and I have granted `MyRole` execute permissions to `MyStoredProcedure`.

But then I get the error:

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'MyDatabase'.

Questions:

1. Am I correct to assume that this is because CTE creates a table?
2. How do I give MyRole as little access as possible to create the CTE, but not alter to everything?

Note:

It has been impossible for me to search for the answer so feel free to edit or post the correct words to help people that search gets more help.

Comment: When you try to execute the `stored procedure` you are getting `CREATE TABLE permission denied` error, is that right?

Comment: I get the error in some C# code, but I am fairly certain it is an SQL error

Comment: "Am I correct to assume that this is because CTE creates a table?" - No this definitely isn't the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a useful answer, but I had overlooked a

```
SELECT * INTO MyTable2
```

I had no idea that potentially could generate a create since MyTable2 always exist

Comment: That's  because your syntax. You need to change to `INSERT INTO MyTable2 SELECT * ...`.